# creating a shm file from kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ipc, shared-memory, kernel-module

I am trying to open a shm file for data sharing between kernel and user process.
Below is my kernel module code.  Sys log output indicates that no errors were encountered.  Once the module is loaded, I don't see the file that I'm trying to create in /dev/shm.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/shmem_fs.h>

static int __init moduleLoader(void) {
    struct file *shfile;

    printk(KERN_INFO "shkmod is loading...\n");

    shfile = shmem_file_setup("MyShmFile",sizeof(int),0);
    printk("shmem_file_setup returned %p\n",shfile);
    if (IS_ERR(shfile))
        printk("shmem_file_setup returned error.\n");
    printk("shfile is: %s\n", shfile->f_path.dentry->d_name.name);

    printk(KERN_INFO "shkmod is done loading.\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit moduleUnloader(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "shkmod was unloaded.\n");
    return;
}

module_init(moduleLoader);
module_exit(moduleUnloader);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Yaron Shragai");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
```

Here is the output in the sys log:

```
Jun  6 15:25:59 yaron-VirtualBox kernel: [457160.335482] shkmod is loading...
Jun  6 15:25:59 yaron-VirtualBox kernel: [457160.335487] shmem_file_setup returned ffff8801fef53b00
Jun  6 15:25:59 yaron-VirtualBox kernel: [457160.335488] shfile is: MyShmFile
Jun  6 15:25:59 yaron-VirtualBox kernel: [457160.335488] shkmod is done loading.
```

$ uname -a
Linux yaron-VirtualBox 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: add "C" tag to your question that will help you.

Comment: OK, added "c" tag! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * shmem_file_setup - get an unlinked file living in tmpfs
```

The comment explicitly states the file is not going to appear anywhere.

```
 * @name: name for dentry (to be seen in /proc/<pid>/maps
```

... and the name is to have something to be shown in maps.

```
 * @size: size to be set for the file
 * @flags: VM_NORESERVE suppresses pre-accounting of the entire object size
 */
struct file *shmem_file_setup(const char *name, loff_t size, unsigned long flags)
{
        return __shmem_file_setup(name, size, flags, 0);
}
```

It makes sense though. You did not specify any filesystem, just used a name which is a relative path to begin with. Why did you expect the file to show up in /dev specifically?

As usual the real question is what is the actual problem you are working on.

If it happens that a shared file is indeed the way to go, userspace should create one and tell the kernel to use it.

Comment: Would have to respond to you in several posts, due to character limits in comments.

Comment: > The comment explicitly states the file is not going to appear anywhere.

This may be a dumb question that exposes me as a noob, but, how is it stating that?

Comment: I don't always trust comments on kernel functions, b/c I've seen some gross cut-n-paste errors.
`shmem_file_setup()` calls `__shmem_file_setup()`, which contains:
`    ....
    this.name = name;
    ....
    sb = shm_mnt->mnt_sb;
    path.mnt = mntget(shm_mnt);
    path.dentry = d_alloc_pseudo(sb, &this);
    ....`
shm_mnt presumably refers to /dev/shm, b/c that's the shmfs (aka tmpfs).  /dev/shm is where a file is created when you call the user-space API shmem_open().

Comment: > If a shared file is indeed the way to go, userspace should create one and tell the kernel to use it. --> Initially I was in fact hoping to have the user process allocate shared memory via shmem_open(), and have my external kernel module essentially mmap it.  In user-space this is a piece of cake: shmem_open() to open or find a shared memory object by name (which is backed up by a file in /dev/shm), and mmap it by the fd returned by shmem_open().  But I couldn't find a kernel-module API to accomplish this simply.

Comment: I need a kernel module to sporadically send state data to a user process. Looked at Generic Netlink - but GeNetlink is basically designed for (1) User process sends a request to kernel, kernel responds (would require my user process to send continuous requests); or (2) Kernel multicasts to a group that user process subscribes to (I'd rather not multicast due to security concerns). I got stuck with GeNetlink, so looked into shared memory - still requires user process to poll, but I thought it would be easier... (Ended up doing GeNL multicast.)

Comment: "unlinked" means there is no name. You can use netlink and do credentials check or handroll a queue accessible through a device node. Processes would poll the device or just block on read naturally waiting for new events to appear. If the rate of events is supposed to be high you may want to check how fs/aio.c is doing things.

Comment: I see I misread your original /dev/shm path as just /dev. I see where the original suspicion a file would appear there is coming from, but it has to be verified. Distrust towards comments is definitely commendable, but it once more prompts verification - if something souds suspicious, read the code and see. It is unlikely a comment would be wrong about something as fundemntal as the created file being unlinked.